# Calculation of limit of a sequence

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ be a integer such that $d \geq 0$

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be a complex number such that $\Re(z)>0$

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be a real number such that $a>0$

How to calculate this limit?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\dfrac
{
\left|
\left(
\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}
\right)^d
\cdot
\left(
\dfrac{n}{n+1}
\right)^{z-a}
-
1
\right|
}
{
\left|
\dfrac
{\ln(n)^d}
{n^{z+a}}
\right|
}
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use $\ln(1+1/n)=1/n+O(1/n^2)$
and $(1+1/n)^r =1+r/n+O(1/n^2)$.

Take more terms if needed.